# Does anyone know a similar dataset for training a neural network?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for an eCommerce dataset, which works with implict data and should be suitable for a neuronal network. This dataset should be equivalent to the [Spotify Million Playlist Dataset Challenge](https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/spotify-million-playlist-dataset-challenge) (please see below)
[image]

Instead of the tracks, there should be the order with different articles. The dataset that I'm looking for should be:

```
"order": [
               {
                   "orderid": "01", 
                   "order_at": 1493424000, 
                   "num_articels": 5,
                   "price": 120.85 
                   "articels": [
                       {
                           "pos": 0, 
                           "articel_name": "Apple", 
                           "articel_id": "articel1545", 
                           "price": 12.45, 
                   "amount": 2, 
                       }, 
                       {
                           "pos": 0, 
                           "articel_name": "Banana", 
                           "articel_id": "articel1585", 
                           "price": 5.45, 
                   "amount": 1, 
                       }, 
                      ...
                  }
```

It doesn't matter if json, csv or other formats.

Does someone know a dataset that is similar to what I'm looking for? Thanks for suggestions, ideas and answers!